# Will a professional PL s35 anamorphic lens cover a fuji sensor and provide proper squeeze?

Tags: lenses

I have a fuji x-mount camera which is aps-c. As far as I understand it aps-c is just about the same size as super35, and I can buy a PL mount adapter for my fuji camera. Does this mean if i use something like an Atlas Orion 2x i would actually get a 2x squeeze? Or is there some other limiting factor I'm not understanding here. I can't seem to find videos or forums talking about using pro cine anamorphics on fuji, only those 1.3x sirui lenses made for fuji. Maybe I'm not even asking the right question.